# JavaScript: Sort Array String by Number then Letter

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ember.js

I am looking to sort an array containing movie title strings such as:

```
['Battleship','101 Dalmatians','Alice, Sweet Alice','40 Days of Night', '303 Fear Faith Revenge'...]
```

My expected output from this would be:

```
101 Dalmatians
303 Fear Faith Revenge
40 Days of Night
Alice, Sweet, Alice
Battleship
```

I am trying the following which gets close:

```
getMoviesInAlpOrder() {
    const movieList = this.getMovies();
    return movieList.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.title.toLowerCase() > b.title.toLowerCase();
    });
}
```

This almost works but does have some conflicts when sorting the numbers versus character titles. Any suggestions on how best to handle this type of request?

Comment: What is your expected output? Also, how should it sort `['200','3']`?

Comment: The expected output should be as it currently is shown in the array. However, going forward, I can't always assume my entries will be in correct order. A title such as '200 Nights' should come before '303 Fear Faith Revenge' which should come before '40 Days of Night' and so on.

Comment: Updated my question to be more clear about my expected results.

Comment: Your current code [works fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/278obk0r/). Can you give an example which shows the problem?

Comment: @4castle [It doesn't](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785/1048572)

Comment: "*… but does have some conflicts when sorting the numbers versus character titles.*" - Please show us an example with such a conflict. What does your current code output, and what did you expect instead?

Comment: @Bergi I'm not saying it's good code, I'm just saying it works for their example, so they need a better one.

Comment: @4castle: But I'm saying it's *wrong* code, and does not even work for their example depending on the sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the other answers are correct, I think the following solution will be a bit more flexible.

Using [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) should solve your issue (and possibly future issues if you get text with accented characters!). Especially with movie titles, I'd expect there to be some foreign characters to sort.

```
getMoviesInAlpOrder() {
    const movieList = this.getMovies();
    return movieList.sort(function(a, b) {
        var lowerCaseA = a.title.toLocaleLowerCase();
        var lowerCaseB = b.title.toLocaleLowerCase();
        return lowerCaseA.localeCompare(lowerCaseB);
    });
}
```

Comment: That looks to work. I will have to read about localeCompare to understand what this is exactly doing. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
var arr = ['Battleship','101 Dalmatians','Alice, Sweet Alice','40 Days of Night', '303 Fear Faith Revenge'];
console.log(arr.sort());
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply using `movieList.sort()` should work. If you don't provide a compare function, it converts elements to a string and compares based on each character's unicode values. So, "10" will come before "2", and "303" will come before "40".

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort